# Problems with applink.c file when creating a dll

Tags: c++, c, .net, openssl

I'm trying to write a dll for .net in C/C++ using the OpenSSL library. The problem that I encountered is that when I try to call methods from that dll in the .net app it throws the following error:
OPENSSL_Uplink(00007FFD10D33D30,08): no OPENSSL_Applink. The problem is that I can't include applink.c in the .net app and I can't find any way to avoid this error. Does anyone know how could I avoid this error?

Comment: why can't you include applink.c in your c++ library?

Comment: I did that, but didn't help